# What if T is void in Generics? How to omit angle brackets

Tags: c#, generics, void

I have a class of this type:

```
class A<TResult>
{
     public TResult foo();
}
```

But sometimes I need to use this class as a non generic class, ie the type `TResult` is `void`.
I can't instantiate the class in the following way:

```
var a = new A<void>();
```

Also, I'd rather not specify the type omitting the angle brackets:

```
var a = new A();
```

I don't want re-write the whole class because it does the same thing.

Comment: @Davio yes, but it is horrible...

Comment: In that case you have to create a separate class `A` without the constraint. But how do the class implementation look like without T? you have a `T foo()` method on it. What should T be in case of void?

Comment: If you have the need, then make a non-generic equivalent class.

Comment: you can hide the horriblness by `class A:A<object>{}`

Comment: @Rafal write your answer if it works.

Comment: yes, it works. I'm also waiting for Rafal's answer so I can upvote.

Comment: If `TResult` is `void` that means there is no `TResult`. You can't have a generic type without a type constraint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `void` isn't a real type in C#, even there is a corresponding `System.Void` struct in FCL. I'm afraid you need a non-generic version here like this:

```
class A
{
   //non generic implementation
}

class A<T> : A
{
   //generic implementation 
}
```

you can see in FCL there are `System.Action`/`System.Action<T>`, instead of `System.Action<void>`, as well as `Task` instead of `Task<void>`.

**EDIT** From [CLI specification(ECMA-335)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf):

> The following kinds of type cannot be used as arguments in
> instantiations (of generic types or methods):
>
> Byref types (e.g., System.Generic.Collection.List`1<string&> is
> invalid)
>
> Value types that contain fields that can point into the CIL evaluation stack (e.g.,List<System.RuntimeArgumentHandle>)
>
> void (e.g.,List<System.Void> is invalid)

Answer (score 4):

As I posted in comment you can make it look good by inheriting from generic class:

```
class A:A<object>
{
}
```

This clearly hides the generic parameter but be aware that in my experience this is the wrong way to inherit classes and every time I did this I regretted it while my class got more complex.

Comment: instead i can reuse a class with hundreds of lines of code, adding only a few dozen with this trick +1

Answer (score 1):

void is simply not a type in C#, so you cannot have it as a type parameter. But nonetheless, there are times you want a functionnality as if it was one.

In this kind of case, you may make use of a simple replacement type, most likely a very small sruct, such as [System.Reactive.Unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.unit%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) used in Reactive Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Another Option (which seems to be what falanwe was getting at) is to use the NullObject Design Pattern.
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object